# Show only which files has been added to repo

Tags: svn

I have 2 svn `branches(xxx,yyy)` with many revisions.
How to show which `NEW FILES` have to `yyy` branch?

I didnt mean diff. I just want which files has been add.

Thax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use svn log command along with grep as shown below:

```
svn log -r rev1:rev2 | xargs grep -i 'add'
```

This will give you file additions between 2 branches.

Comment: Thax. But i have 2 branches as separated trunks. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean to say that branches are part of different trees. In that case how will you decide which point to compare?